# Python Regex: Loop through first line of each file in directory

Tags: python, regex, loops

I want to loop through .txt files and use the date (e.g. April 1, 1993) from the first line in that file.

This code works, but matches through the entire file and not just the first line (note: the code Im showing below shows more than just the date matching loop):

**Script below is updated and it works:**

```
articles = glob.glob("*.txt")
y = 1

for f in articles:
    with open(f, "r") as content:
        wordcount = "x"
        lines = content.readlines()
        for line in lines :
            if line[0:7] == "LENGTH:":
                lineclean = re.sub('[#%&\<>*?:/{}$@+|=]', '', line)
                wordcount = lineclean[7:13]
                if wordcount[5] == "w":
                    wordcount = wordcount[0:4]
                elif wordcount[4] == "w":
                    wordcount = wordcount[0:3]
                elif wordcount[3] == "w":
                    wordcount =  wordcount[0:2]
                elif wordcount[2] == "w":
                    wordcount =  wordcount[0:1]
    with open(f, "r") as content:
        first_line = next(content)
        try:
            import re
            match = re.search('(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}', first_line).group()
        except:
            pass           
        from dateutil import parser  
        parsed_pubdate = parser.parse(match).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')                  
    try:
        if wordcount != "x":
            move(f, "{parsed_pubdate}_{wordcount}_{source}.txt".format(**locals()))
        else:
            pass
    except OSError:
        pass
    y += 1
    content.close()
```

In order to match dates only in the first line of the file, I add `^\s` and `flags=re.MULTILINE`, so I get:

```
match = re.search('^\s(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?
|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?
|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}', line, flags=re.MULTILINE).group()
```

However, now the program only uses one date (the date of the last file in the folder) and uses that for every file (so every file gets the same date, while the dates vary in the original .txt files).

I uncluded the entire step this loop is part of, but my problem only applies to the regex date matching loop. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since you're removing ":", you should start your wordcount on 6, no?
If you want only check the first line, why don't you firs_line = content.readlines()[0]?

Comment: @AlfredoMiranda: I would prefere `first_line = next(content)` to avoid reading all the lines to later discard all but the first one...

Comment: I tried `first_line = content.readlines()[0]` but it gives exactly the same problem as the 'first line specifyer' in the Regex. That is, it only uses the date from one .txt file and applies that to every file.

Re: the word count. That works fine in the current script.

Comment: Your indentation is off on line 5, which could be causing issues.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank, I now tried `first_line = next(content)`, but again, every file is named with the same date (i.e. 1993-04-01, the date of the last file in my folder).

Comment: @alex I see, this happened when copy-pasting it to the window above, in my editor the indention is fine.

Comment: Python is indentation-sensitive - can you re-post your code with the correct formatting?

Comment: @Rens I ran here and is everything okay. It seems that is some indentation issue.

Comment: @AlfredoMiranda I reposted my code, with the `first_line = content.readlines()[0]` as you suggested. Do I use it properly? I will post the code on Github too, as that is perhaps less sensitive for indentation.

Comment: This still won't solve the problem, but for the sake of not reading the whole file, `content.readline()` makes more sense than `content.readlines()[0]`.

Comment: I now see that I did wrong: I shouldn't have add `for line in first_line:` after  `first_line = content.readlines()[0]`, now the code works. So to improve it, I will use the `next(content)` (which equals `content.readline()` if I understand it well)

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and help! I updated the code above, which does now exactly what I need :-)

Comment: Good to know that is working now! And @glibdud, you are totally right. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
articles = glob.glob("*.txt")
y = 1

for f in articles:
    with open(f, "r") as content:
        wordcount = "x"
        lines = content.readlines()
        for line in lines :
            if line[0:7] == "LENGTH:":
                lineclean = re.sub('[#%&\<>*?:/{}$@+|=]', '', line)
                wordcount = lineclean[7:13]
                if wordcount[5] == "w":
                    wordcount = wordcount[0:4]
                elif wordcount[4] == "w":
                    wordcount = wordcount[0:3]
                elif wordcount[3] == "w":
                    wordcount =  wordcount[0:2]
                elif wordcount[2] == "w":
                    wordcount =  wordcount[0:1]
    with open(f, "r") as content:
        first_line = next(content)
        try:
            import re
            match = re.search('(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}', first_line).group()
        except:
            pass           
        from dateutil import parser  
        parsed_pubdate = parser.parse(match).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')                  
    try:
        if wordcount != "x":
            move(f, "{parsed_pubdate}_{wordcount}_{source}.txt".format(**locals()))
        else:
            pass
    except OSError:
        pass
    y += 1
    content.close()
```